# WMS - Multiple paramters in CQL_FILTER not working?

Tags: geoserver, cql-filter

I'm doing a WMS request with 2 `cql_filters`. This is the resultant query:

> ?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=tmp_vista_expedientes&cql_filter=strSubstring(FecRegistro%2C0%2C4)%3D2018;strSubstring(codigo,0,3)=%27201%27&time=1573127644387&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A25830&STYLES=&BBOX=0
>   ... 0

Basically I have 2 filters:

```
strSubstring(FecRegistro,0,4)=2018
```

And

```
strSubstring(codigo,0,3)='201'
```

Separating them with a semicolon `;`. But only the first filter is applied.

> How can I make both filters be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to filter two distinct layers then you need to separate the filters with `;` but if you are trying to combine two (or more) filters on a **single** layer then you need to use `and` or `or` as joining commands.

So in your case I would apply:

```
strSubstring(FecRegistro,0,4)=2018 or strSwhubstring(codigo,0,3)='201'
```

which will return all filters which match either of the filters. or

```
strSubstring(FecRegistro,0,4)=2018 and strSubstring(codigo,0,3)='201'
```

which will return any feature that matches both of the filters.

Comment: Dude! You are everywhere haha! As always you were right, thanks for real for your labour